# How do I correctly use CoInitialize() and CoInitializeSecurity() as if I didn't call the latter so I can use IGlobalOptions?

Tags: c, winapi, com

My UI is provided in a DLL that calls `CoInitialize()` so I can use the Common Item Dialog, shell open folder dialog. and any other new Vista-only stuff that may require COM (I don't know of/don't use any others just yet). The DLL will also provide a UI Automation interface to a custom control (my Table control from questions past, which I've decided to move to UI Automation).

I don't want [COM's "helpful" exception handling](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/01/20/10117963.aspx); I want exceptions in my DLL to bubble through to the DLL so they can be debugged. However, [the documentation for IGlobalOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa344211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says I need to call `CoInitializeSecurity()` beforehand.

I have two questions:

1. Do I call `CoInitializeSecurity()` instead of or in addition to `CoInitialize()`? If in addition to, do I call it before or after?
2. What would the invocation be if I wanted COM to act as if I didn't call `CoInitializeSecurity()` at all? After reading MSDN I know what most of the parameters should be, but I'm not sure about some of them.

   ```
   CoInitializeSecurity(
       NULL,
       -1,    // or is the default 0 instead?
       /* can this be NULL? (the error returns table on MSDN implies it can...) if not, what should I specify? */,
       NULL,
       RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,
       /* what should this be? MSDN says RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_DEFAULT isn't allowed */,
       /* can this be NULL? if not, what should I specify? */,
       /* what should this be? MSDN says EOAC_DEFAULT isn't allowed */,
       NULL);
   ```

   Or is this completely wrong both security-wise and defaults-wise and there's a better option?

Or should I not even bother doing any of this since this is a DLL?

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, no, you don't have to call it, nobody uses Vista anymore.  Boilerplate [is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: From the sounds of things this problem may not apply to you. There's nothing to catch these exceptions if you're only using umarshalled interfaces. You might want to try throwing an uncaught exception in UI Automation interface to there's actually anything there to catch it.

Comment: Goes to show how important quotes are: Current docs for IGlobalOptions (your link) doesn't mention any CoInitializeSecurity requirements.

Answer (score 1):

PS: I'm assuming your library doesn't contain the actual `main()` code.

> My UI is provided in a DLL that calls CoInitialize()...

I hope you're doing this in your own thread, otherwise you're asking for trouble.

> 1. Do I call CoInitializeSecurity()...

Don't do this in a library, it's a process-wide call, which might be done by the application itself or when cross-apartment marshaling happens for the first time.

> 2. What would the invocation be...

I'd say [this is it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393617(v=vs.85).aspx), if no registry information is found.  To quote:

```
CoInitializeSecurity(NULL, -1, NULL, NULL, 
    RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, 
    NULL, EOAC_NONE, NULL);
```

> Or is this completely wrong both security-wise and defaults-wise and there's a better option?

There are better options.

One is to return a constructed HRESULT and store your actual error description in one of your DLL's globals, perhaps using thread-local storage.

If you're using ATL, you may use such an HRESULT and end up using the same information you'd feed to your `CComCoClass::Error` method, which your objects most probably use as a template inheritance.

Or just use ATL's error handling, it might be enough since you can breakpoint your own code anyway.

> Or should I not even bother doing any of this since this is a DLL?

It actually depends on thread ownership.  If you own the thread where this happens, it's OK; if not, it's clearly wrong.

But consider alternatives like the ones I suggested.

Comment: I'm not sure how the options you suggested would change things. We're talking about system exceptions like NULL pointer accesses that COM intercepts and handles for us; I want to be able to handle them myself, be it by returning an HRESULT or other means. But if I can't even get to take action, the point is moot! The DLL doesn't contain `main()`; it contains an `init()` function that is called by `main()`, and that calls its own `CoInitialize()` (since I use the Common Item Dialog, which requires COM).

Comment: So your DLL contains the application code (it doesn't contain `main`, but it has the *main* code), that's relevant and should be in your question.  Typically, DLLs are used as libraries, so they should leave process-wide settings and the state of a thread they don't own alone.  Also, you want to let all exceptions unhandled, so you can debug them (you can debug first-chance exceptions, anyway).  Usually, you should create a barrier in COM methods that maps application exceptions to COM errors/HRESULTs.  This makes most of my answer, which assumed the typical DLL, mostly useless for you.